# Use GoogleMap in asp.net project when i'm offline

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

I have an asp.net web project that i want to use googleMap to show my places on it , the problem is : it works only when i'm online but i want to cache images and use it even when i haven't access to internet, i searched a lot about using googlemap offline but couldn't find usefull thing. how can i cache google map images for ofline use ? or sth like that ?

Thanks

Comment: What about Maps Image API? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/ - you should somehow cache images locally ...

Comment: Thanks xeondev, could you tell me how can i use "Google Maps Image API" in Asp.Net ? is it possible ?

Comment: It's just a URL you construct to get an image, you can use if from anything you like. How hard can it be?

Comment: And maybe this can help you. http://sdesmedt.wordpress.com/2007/10/25/google-offline-library-changed-name-to-offline-maps-and-added-elevation-tiles/

Comment: @Strelok and can I use the image just like the images in googleMap , I mean , can I use markers ? can I get the cordinates of a point ? can I use zoom ?

Comment: No, Its just a static image like this: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-15.800513,-47.91378&zoom=11&size=200x200&sensor=false

Comment: So I can't use it :( , its just a map ,do you have any other idea for my problem ? how can i have sth like google map in my web site that works offline too ?

Comment: @SpzSpz Read the developer docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index It supports markers, paths and a few other features, but no you can't use other features. You can't use the full Google Maps API offline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 offline google map access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162016/html5-offline-google-map-access)